# why checkbox with ViewHelper posts only zero always

Tags: zend-framework, post, checkbox, zend-form, decorator

checkbox value is always `0` (no matter checked or unchecked) when i define

`$cbxElement->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));`

however, after removing the same, checkbox value posts well (`1` for checked and `0` for unchecked)

my question is why the checkbox exhibits this behavior and

what does `setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'))` actually doing to the checkbox element?

Also, why does `Zend_View_Helper_FormCheckbox` automatically adds a hidden field preceding a checkbox as long as it does not have the form `name[]`?

Answer (score 1):

`setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'))` removes `dt` and `dd` tags, hidden fields are not the problem. If you want your checkbox value = 1 try this:

```
$yourCheckBox->setValue(1);
```

Comment: why removing of dt and dd tags affects the checkbox post value?

Comment: No dt and dd tags dont affects the checkbox post value , you ask "what does setDecorators(array('ViewHelper')) actually doing to the checkbox element?" and I tell you ViewHelper remove dt and dd tags.

Comment: you addressed only one part of the question